# Find data from coordinates in Arrow DB

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-arrow, arrowdb

After reading docs https://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/guide/customfields I coud not find any way to get data from coordinates with arrow DB projet (when you deploy it in the cloud !).

I try this :

```
req.model.query({
    coordinates: {
        "$nearSphere": [50.8331170,4.3846790], // test values
        "$maxDistance": 0.1
    }
}, next);
```

My model look like this :

```
var Arrow = require('arrow');

var Model = Arrow.createModel('test', {
    fields: {
        coordinates: {
            type: Array
        },
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        description: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    connector: 'appc.arrowdb',
    autogen: false
});

module.exports = Model;
```

To be clear I want to find some data around a "location"
Someone have an idea for that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use $geonear, it is mentioned in https://docs.appcelerator.com/arrowdb/latest/#!/guide/search_query, search for nearsphere

Comment: I already check that, but i'm talking about the Arrow Builder. Not Arrow DB/ old ACS. As you can see in my post I already tried that ...